# Align textbox and shape in Word via VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

### Problem 1

In MS Word, the Align commands as pictured below, do not work on textboxes. I have a textbox and a shape and would like them centered together.

[image: Align commands]

### Solution

I'd like to write a VBA sub that'd take care of this. It is however quite complicated to determine which two objects are selected, especially if they're on a canvas or only one of them is on a canvas. It seems easier to read their names off the Selection taskpane.

### Problem 2

How to determine which objects are highlighted on the Selection pane? In the example below, I'd like VBA to know that "3-Point Star 10" and "3-Point Star 9" are selected.

[image: Selection taskpane]

Comment: in Word, a textbox is simply a shape that contains text and can be aligned with other shapes using the Align menu in Word. Perhaps you are using the term "textbox" to refer to something that isn't a "textbox", in which case you need to [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71330307/edit) and provide more details of what you mean.

Comment: Actually, it works now, I can't determine the reason it wasn't working yesterday. I have a document packed full of diagrams and Word is acting strangely, sometimes its window goes all black, sometimes the cursor in VBA editor isn't visible, sometimes keyboard shortcuts don't work. Will definitely look more closely into this, thanks.